# Shortcut using WIX

Tags: wix, exe, shortcut

I have an installer that creates a folder "_source" in the targetdir, which contains the "SAMPLE.exe" and other files.  I am trying to generate a shortcut that will point to that exe but it seems to generate/copy that exe and place it in the target directory.  Its able to run the executable but since other files are needed in the _source directory, it cannot continue.  How do I point to the exe in _source without making a copy of that exe?

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
       <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" SourceName="Desktop"/>
          <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder">
             <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="1D120AC7-6BAC-4F99-8611-029ED3F2EA3A">
             <File Id="MyExeFile" Source="!(wix._source)\SAMPLE.exe" KeyPath="yes">
             <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="SAMPLE" WorkingDirectory="MergeRedirectFolder"
                 Icon="SAMPLE.exe"
                 IconIndex="0"
                 Advertise="yes" >
                 <Icon Id="SAMPLE.exe" SourceFile="!(wix._source)\icon1.ico" />
             </Shortcut>
           </File>
         </Component>
      </Directory>
```

Comment: is MergeRedirectFolder on your desktop?  This looks like you are trying to install this to a folder on your desktop.

Comment: the SAMPLE.exe is installed under '_source' located in the targetdir.  I would like to have the shortcut in the desktop, pointing to the exe in the _source folder.  With the code above, it doesnt create a folder in desktop, it just create a shortcut but doesnt seem to point to the exe from _source.

Comment: It created a copy of SAMPLE.exe and placed it in the targetdir, outside of _source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to install under program files, i would start with something like this:

```
<Product ...>
...
<Feature ...>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
</Feature>
<Icon Id="SAMPLE.ico" SourceFile="!(wix._source)\icon1.ico" />
</Product>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder" />
    </Directory>

    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" SourceName="Desktop"/>        
</Directory>

<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="MergeRedirectFolder">
    <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="1D120AC7-6BAC-4F99-8611-029ED3F2EA3A">
        <File Id="MyExeFile" Source="!(wix._source)\SAMPLE.exe" KeyPath="yes">
            <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="SAMPLE" WorkingDirectory="MergeRedirectFolder"
             Icon="SAMPLE.ico"
             IconIndex="0"
             Advertise="yes" />
        </File>
    </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```